# EditText as part of HeaderView loses focus on input

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

This is an issue which I am facing only for > Android 4.0 devices.

Currently I have a listView and a custom header which I add onCreate()of the ListActivity.

I use the editText as a custom searchBar in the app.

The following is a code snippet which hopefully explains my implementation.

```
private ListView    lst_Reports = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.showreportlist);

    lst_Reports = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.VuoShowReportsActivity_Lst_Reports);

    /*
     * Initialize UI
     */

    LinearLayout headerView = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.report_list_header, null);
    EditText reportSearchBar = (EditText) headerView.findViewById(R.id.reportSearchBar);
    lst_Reports.addHeaderView(headerView);

    reportSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // do a search as and when the user inputs text

            if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {

                String query = s.toString();
                List queriedReports = getReportsBasedOnQueryString(query);

             // populate the listView with the queriedReports

            }

        }

    });

}

protected List getReportsBasedOnQueryString(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

When this code is executed on Android 2.3.5 device, then I can type normally in the editText. However when the same piece of code is deployed on Galaxy S3 which has Ice cream sandwich, I am able to only enter one character at a time in the editText since it keeps losing focus after every key input.

I have already tried the following proposed solutions to similar problems. None of them have solved the issue.

- to the activity in AndroidManifest:

  - android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
  - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
- in the layout xml of the activity:

  - android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

I appreciate any help/feedback on this and am also keen to know if anyone else has reported the same issue.

Thanks 
Rajat

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // do a search as and when the user inputs text

        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {

            String query = s.toString();
            List queriedReports = getReportsBasedOnQueryString(query);

         // populate the listView with the queriedReports

        }
         // add below line in your code
         reportSearchBar.requestFocus();


    }
```